# How do I use a dropdown menu in a cell to populate other cells with information?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to build a spreadsheet that allows a user to select a product in a dropdown menu in the first cell and then based on what is selected it will populate the spreadsheet with prices and products included. I have zero idea how to go about doing this as I'm incredibly novice at this. Gotta learn somehow though.

Comment: Why don't you take the [tour] and get yourself familiar and earn that badge. Welcome on Web Applications !!

Answer (score 3):

See this [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J7V3rrCIe0K-0gZJWsnTCJep9hkPydLrii4xME4WvAk/edit#gid=1543039727) spreadsheet. Sheet `Countries` contains source data (instead of prices and products, I've used countries, population and other data, but the concept is the same). Sheet `Dropdown` contains the example. In that latter sheet, cell `C1` and `E1` are dropdown menus (use the `Data→Validation…` menu to see how data validation works, or look at the explanations at the bottom of this answer).

Then, in cell `A2`, you have a query that fetches data from the `Countries` sheet, based on the values present in your dropdown menus. The trick is to build the query string using the string concatenation operator (`&`). What the query string says is: fetch data from columns A to E of the `Countries` sheet, where column C is lower than `Dropdown!C1` and column E is lower than `Dropdown!E1`.

**Note** that you will need to copy the example spreadsheet to play with it (you can only comment the original).

***Explanations***
To set a cell as a drop down menu, select the cell, then use the `Data→Validation…` menu. For instance, for cell `C1` of the `Dropdown` sheet,[image: list of items]
you can enter the list of values you want users to select from by setting the `Criteria` to **List of items** and then enter comma separated values in the input box right next to it. Other options of this validation menu are self explanatory.

Another common dropdown menu is where you want users to select values from a range within the spreadsheet: [image: list from range]
As you can see here, the `Criteria`  is now set to **List from a range**. You enter the range itself by clicking on the grid within the input box, and then by selecting the range of cells you want to use as your selectable items. In the case of our examples, the values come from the sheet `Population range` where I made some computations to generate a log scale list of values between the smallest country population and the largest.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the post Jean-Rene. OP has _zero idea_, so explaining how to build a drop-down would be helpful as well.

Comment: Drop downs I managed. I figured that out and got stuck. Thanks for the comment! I'll play with this and see what I can accomplish.

Comment: Hi Voxil, I added some more explanations. If you find it useful, you can use the arrows next to my answer to state so.